# Calculate peak concurrent users on a website

Tags: internet

I am looking at setting up some website load testing scripts and need some help in finding a formula to estimate how many concurrent users are browsing a website at peak times, based on common metrics such as visits, average page views per visit, and average visit duration.

For example:

Peak visitors per hour: 1,000

Average page views per visitor: 3

Average time per visit: 5 minutes

Should I be considering at any other stats? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is average page views per visitor relevant if you have average time per visit? Do you care if a five minute visit has 100 page views or 2 in order to count the number of concurrent users (assuming 'concurrent' means 'visiting')?

Comment: I suspect you need to model the visitor, then use queuing theory to do your analysis.  How detailed your visitor model is is up to you.